# A question about valuations (in the proof of Hartshorne's proposition II6.2 )

Tags: algebraic-geometry

On page 132 of Hartshorne's *Algebraic Geometry*, the author reduced the proof of Proposition II6.2 to the proof of

> if $A$ is an integrally closed domain, then every prime ideal of height $1$ is principal if and only if Cl(Spec $A$)$=0$.

The author says

> $Y$ corresponds to a prime ideal $\mathfrak p$ of hight $1$. If $\mathfrak p$ is generated by an element $f \in A$, then clearly the divisor of $f$ is $1 \cdot Y$.

By definition, $v_Y$ is the valuation on the function field of $X:= $ Spec $A$ defining $\mathcal O_{X, \eta}$ for $\eta$ the generic point of $Y$. So $v_Y(f)$ must be $>0$ since $f$ is in the maximal ideal of $\mathcal O_{X,\eta}$.

But why should $v_Y(f)$ be $1$? Can it be an integer $n>1$? I don't kow whether or not the image of this valuation should be all of $\mathbb Z$.

Being kind of opposed to this question is another one coming from line 13.

> Since $v_Y(f)=1$, we have $f \in A_{\mathfrak p}$, and $f$ generates $\mathfrak p A_{\mathfrak p}$.

Why do we know that $f$ generates $\mathfrak pA_{\mathfrak p}$? More generally, for a discrete valuation ring $D$ with valuation $v$ and an element $d \in D$, does $v(d)=1$ imply $d$ generates the maximal ideal of $D$?

I am sorry I don't type everything here.

Thanks to everyone.

Comment: For the first question, you should remind yourself what $v_\mathfrak{p}$ means. Namely, since $A_\mathfrak{p}$ is a DVR you know that $\mathfrak{p}=(\pi)$ for some $\pi$, and then $v_\mathfrak{p}(f)$ is the integer $n$ such that $\pi^n$ and $f$ differ by a unit. Now, if $\mathfrak{p}=(f)$, then $\mathfrak{p}A_\mathfrak{p}=(f)$ so you can take $f=\pi$. The second question follows from a similar analysis.

Comment: Maybe it would be good to review the basics of discrete valuation rings. I think section 12.5 of Vakil's notes is good for this.